# What is wrong in the code... Subtree of Another Tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am looking at LeetCode problem [572. Subtree of Another Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/subtree-of-another-tree/):

> Given the roots of two binary trees `root` and `subRoot`, return `true` if there is a subtree of `root` with the same structure and node values of `subRoot` and `false` otherwise.
>
> A subtree of a binary tree `tree` is a tree that consists of a node in `tree` and all of this node's descendants. The tree `tree` could also be considered as a subtree of itself.
>
> #### Example 1
>
> ```
> Input:  root = [3,4,5,1,2], subRoot = [4,1,2]
> Output:  true
> ```
>
> #### Example 2
>
> ```
> Input: root = [3,4,5,1,2,null,null,null,null,0], subRoot = [4,1,2]
> Output: false
> ```

### My Code

```
class Solution:
    def isSubtree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], subRoot: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        
        if not root and not subRoot:
            return True
        if root==None or subRoot==None:
            return False
        
        if root.val == subRoot.val and self.isSubtree(root.left,subRoot.left) and self.isSubtree(root.right,subRoot.right):
            return True
        
        return self.isSubtree(root.left,subRoot) or self.isSubtree(root.right,subRoot)
```

**Input Failing:**

```
Input
[3,4,5,1,null,2]
[3,1,2]

Output  True

Expected  False
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your algorithm is that it allows the check to skip some nodes.

The failing test case represents these trees:

```
  root: 3          subRoot: 3
       / \                 / \
      4   5               1   2
     /   /
    1   2
```

In the first call of your function, the roots have equal values, so then this recursive call is made:

```
  root: 4         subRoot: 1
       /
      1
```

Now you can already see that here the `subRoot` **is** a sub tree of `root`, but this fact should not be used here, since we are half-way a tree matching procedure where the original roots already matched, so we are not allowed now to skip over the node 4, yet that is what will happen.

The real problem is that you are trying to cover two recursive needs in one recursive function:

- find a node in `root` where `subRoot` matches with all its descendants
- verify that all descendants match.

You need to split this into two independent recursive functions. For instance:

```
class Solution:
    def isSubtree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], subRoot: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        def recurMatch(root, subRoot):
            return not (subRoot or root) or (
                subRoot and root and 
                root.val == subRoot.val and  
                recurMatch(root.left, subRoot.left) and 
                recurMatch(root.right, subRoot.right)
            )

        def recurSearch(root):
            return root and (
                recurMatch(root, subRoot) or 
                recurSearch(root.left) or 
                recurSearch(root.right)
            )
        
        return bool(recurSearch(root))
```

#### Faster?

The above solution will only perform "average" on LeetCode. You could improve by relying on fast string comparison: stringify both trees and check whether the second string occurs within the first. And the shorter the serialisation you can generate, the faster the algorithm will work.

Spoiler:

> `class Solution:
>      def isSubtree(self, root, subRoot):
>          def stringify(root):
>              return f"[{stringify(root.left) if root.left else ''}{chr(root.val+10128)}{stringify(root.right) if root.right else ''}]"
>          return stringify(subRoot) in stringify(root)`